# Remove a file with a special characters from git

Tags: git

For some annoying reasons, the working tree on my project is showing files which doesn't exists. I would like to get the above entry out of there,

`promo/cnbc/tertiary/1514030668251Paras HMRI Patna - Award Nomination Dec\\'17.pdf`

Comment: They are part of the tree, even if they do not exist at the moment. Did you try `git rm <file>`?

Comment: You can give wildcards to git rm: `git rm promo/cnbc/tertiary/1514030668251*`

Answer (score 0):

Use wildcards:

```
git rm promo/cnbc/tertiary/1514030668251*
```